# ASP NET Как правильно указать картинку в html для веб хостинга?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Добрый день я прописываю картинку в html

```
<img src="~/Resources/MyImage.jpg" Height="200" Width="300">
```

Но когда переношу проект на хостинг он её не находит. Куда её поместить чтобы видеть или в свойства/дополнительно надо что-то менять у картинки или с JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зашел на веб хостинг и посмотрел файлы проекта, оказывается данная папка с картинкой не опубликована, опубликовал и всё сразу заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Если это Razor Page используйте `Url.Content()`

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/MyImage.jpg")" Height="200" Width="300">
```

Ах да, если мне не изменяет память, нельзя просто так взять и положить статические файлы в другую папку. (если это не NET Core)

Проверьте будет ли у Вас работать так еще, переместив картинку в папку Images:

```
<img src="~/Images/MyImage.jpg" Height="200" Width="300">
```

Answer (score -2):

В атрибуте src должден быть либо относительный (от текущей страницы, если без / в начале - или от корня сайта если с /), либо абсолютный (с http:// или https://) путь к картинке. Которая тоже должна быть на хостинге.

А вот эта тильда тут ни к селу ни к городу. В Linux символ ~ используется для сокращенного обозначения домашней директории пользователя, а именно директории /home/<имя пользователя>.

Comment: *"Эта тильда"* является служебным символом в ASP.NET, а Linux тут ни при чём.